# get Contex in extended SQLiteOpenHelper class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have database and i want fill it with some values from xml file. 
I'm using this code `stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.test_entry);` to define the stream, but `context` make error "cannot resolve symbol 'context'". 
I tried replace `context` with `getActivity(), getContext(), this, class name` and it still  doesn't work. I need some help...

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

<...>

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbv);
}


public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {
 <...>
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tableName);
    onCreate(db);
    /////////////////
    loadTestValuyes(); <----- My function
    /////////////////
}


public  void loadTestValuyes() {

    test_addEntry stackOverflowXmlParser = new test_addEntry();
    List<Entry> entries = null;
    InputStream stream = null;

    ///// I need context here
    stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.test_entry);
    /////////////////

    try {
        entries = stackOverflowXmlParser.parse(stream);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }


    for (Entry entry : entries) {
         <...>
    }

}


}
```

Thanks

Comment: you mean `context`, with a `t` at the end

Comment: Yep. You're writing contex, not context.

Comment: Ahm. I made mistake in post. In code i wrote `contexT` and it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `Context` as a constructor argument. Just store it to a member variable:

```
private Context mContext;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbv);
    mContext = context;
```

and then use `mContext` where you need a `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a reference to the Context object as an instance variable and use it wherever you need it:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context mContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbv);
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```